# Angular Jasmine test not finding modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

So my test is complaining that it can't find `ui.bootstrap`

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux)]: Connected on socket 15lSt3HPpk9b-rKPvQzY
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux) Controller: Week should attach days of the week to scope FAILED
    Error: No module: ui.bootstrap
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at /home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1211:17
        at ensure (/home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1152:38)
        at module (/home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1209:14)
        at /home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2904:24
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at forEach (/home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:130:11)
        at loadModules (/home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2900:5)
        at /home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2905:38
        at Array.forEach (native)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'days_of_the_week' of undefined
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/xenoterracide/lm/frontend/test/spec/controllers/week.js:20:17)
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.126 secs / 0.017 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Elapsed time
concurrent:test  1s
```

here's my `app.js` which is where I load `ui.bootstrap`.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('lmApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router'
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
            $stateProvider.state('index', {
                    url: "", // root
                    views: {
                            "Nav":        { templateUrl: "views/nav.html" },
                            "Week":       { templateUrl: "views/week.html" },
                    },
            })
    }
])
.factory('now', function () { return new Date })
;
```

here's my test

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: Week', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('lmApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('Week', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach days of the week to scope', function () {
    expect(scope.days_of_the_week.length).toBe(7);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is stated in the error log when it says:

```
Error: No module: ui.bootstrap
```

Based on that, I'm going to guess you're missing a step in your Karma config file (usually called `karma.conf.js`).  You need to supply all of the necessary libraries that your app requires in your config so that Karma knows to load those up in memory before running your tests.  When you call `beforeEach(module('lmApp'));`, Karma tries to create your `lmApp` module, but can't because one (or more) of its declared dependencies isn't available.

I'm 99% sure that if you just include the source code for `ui.bootstrap` in the `files: {}` portion of your karma config, it should start working.

See the karma docs [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/files.html) for more info.

Comment: For me, I was adding the files with jasmine/rspec to `spec/javascripts/spec_helper.coffee`